# How to clip ggplot to inside a spatialpolygonsdataframe obtained from a shape file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe of the form : LAT LONG VALUE. I am using stat_summary2d to sum up values inside each grid cell.

How can i clip to the shape so that the grid cells at the boundary are smoothened like in this image below?

[image]